# Как улучшить качество (резкость) многостраничного PDF?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

Я читаю сканы рукописных архивов позапрошлого века. В них десятки, а то и сотни страниц. Разрешение высокое, весят от десятков М до пары G.
Пример:
[image: Фрагмент страницы архива]

Comment: Как минимум, добавьте в вопрос пример "нерезкого" скана (фрагмент).

Comment: Хорошие материалы вы читаете. Есть что интересного в записях? Какие года? О чем текст? (извините что не по теме;)
Я ищу хоть какие нибудь записи 1842 и ранее.

Comment: @FrancNet Я с удовольствием пообщаюсь с Вами на эту тему, но не здесь. Можно как-то связаться с Вами лично?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, у вас уже установлен пакет `imagemagick`, а значит есть утилита `convert`.

Можно написать такой скрипт:

```bash
# Создаём папку для обработанных файлов
mkdir processed

# Вытаскиваем все страницы из INPUT.PDF с разрещением 300 DPI
convert -density 300 INPUT.PDF processed/page-%04d.jpg

# Обрабатываем каждую картинку
for f in processed/page-*.jpg
do
    echo "${f##*/}..."

    # Накладываем фильтр unsharp mask с какими-то параметрами.
    # Эти параметры вам придётся выработать самостоятельно.
    # И сохраняем файл с добавлением NEW___ в начале имени.
    convert "$f" -unsharp  10.0x10.0+2.0+1  $(dirname "$f")/NEW___$(basename "$f")
done
```

Сохраните его в `enhancer.sh`, положите в папку, где есть файл INPUT.PDF и запускайте командой `sh enhancer.sh` или `bash enhancer.sh`.

В принципе, можно ещё и собрать отдельные файлы обратно в PDF, добавив в конце скрипта такую команду:

```bash
convert "processed/NEW___*.jpg" -quality 100 "NEW_PDF.pdf"
```

И наверняка, вам пригодится не только фильтр `-unsharp`, но и другие из [огромного количества фильтров](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно! Нашла в библиотеке еще интересные фильтры `-enhance` и  `-contrast`, исследую возможности.
Про `convert -density`  написано, что это меняет только атрибут, а не саму картинку. А чем это нам помогает?

Comment: @user244413 Насколько я помню,`density` устанавливает разрешение при конвертации pdf→jpg. Попробуйте сделать его равным, скажем, 50 и увидите, насколько мелкими получатся jpeg-файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Непосредственно в самом PDF сделать это будет проблематично.

Разбираем страницы PDF на отдельные картинки, обрабатываем отдельную страницу для увеличения резкости и читаемости в Фотошопе, записываем action для обработки и делаем пакетную обработку всех страниц сразу. Потом можно будет снова собрать в PDF, либо читать с картинок с помощью просмотрщика.

Дальше пример отредактированной странички, сделал на скорую руку, можно сделать и лучше, тем более если там разрешение высокое.

[image: отредактированная страница]

Comment: Это хорошее решение, но у меня нет Фотошопа. Вы знаете какие-то другие графические редакторы, которые можно запускать командной строкой? Лучше бесплатные ;)

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову — Gimp, но вот что-то посоветовать конкретно по нему, я, к сожалению не смогу, и не знаю, поддерживает ли он пакетную обработку изображений.